# Converting rgb to lab syntax error in skimage

Tags: python

I'm passing a 3-tuple rgb value to the skimage function rgb2lab (http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.color.html#rgb2lab)

I keep getting this ValueError: `the input array must be have a shape == (.., ..,[ ..,] 3))`.

What does this shape look like? Is it not just a 3-tuple e.g.`(203, 198, 195)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function requires you to pass the **image** in rgb format, not a single color. The shape of an array is pretty much it's dimensions [ref](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html).

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> x.shape
(4,)
>>> y = np.zeros((2, 3, 4))
>>> y.shape
(2, 3, 4)
>>> y.shape = (3, 8)
>>> y
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> y.shape = (3, 6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

passing in a single tuple containing some arbitrary color value won't do much, what you need to do is pass in an image in rgb **format**